Go's bufio internally ignores problematic ErrBufferFull?
I was looking at Go source code and found that, in bufio.Reader.collectFragments (a helper used by ReadSlice and ReadString), a seemingly serious ErrBufferFull is ignored, specifically:
func (b *Reader) collectFragments(delim byte) (fullBuffers [][]byte, finalFragment []byte, totalLen int, err error) {
    var frag []byte
    // Use ReadSlice to look for delim, accumulating full buffers.
    for {
        var e error
        frag, e = b.ReadSlice(delim)
        if e == nil { // got final fragment
            break
        }
        if e != ErrBufferFull { // unexpected error
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This ensures that ErrBufferFull will not break the loop
            err = e
            break
        }

        // Make a copy of the buffer.
        buf := bytes.Clone(frag)
        fullBuffers = append(fullBuffers, buf)
        totalLen += len(buf)
    }

    totalLen += len(frag)
    return fullBuffers, frag, totalLen, err
}

(go/src/bufio/bufio.go, line 446, Go 1.22)
If ReadSlice returns an ErrBufferNull, it is ignored. The full buffer is copied, and a new iteration starts, which calls ReadSlice again.
However, ReadSlice 'fails' when the buffer is full, and doesn't seem to have any logic to grow or clear a full buffer.
func (b *Reader) ReadSlice(delim byte) (line []byte, err error) {
    s := 0 // search start index
    for {
        // Search buffer.
        if i := bytes.IndexByte(b.buf[b.r+s:b.w], delim); i >= 0 {
            i += s
            line = b.buf[b.r : b.r+i+1]
            b.r += i + 1
            break
        }

        // Pending error?
        if b.err != nil {
            line = b.buf[b.r:b.w]
            b.r = b.w
            err = b.readErr()
            break
        }

        // Buffer full?
        if b.Buffered() >= len(b.buf) {
            b.r = b.w
            line = b.buf
            err = ErrBufferFull
            break
        }

        s = b.w - b.r // do not rescan area we scanned before

        b.fill() // buffer is not full
    }

    // Handle last byte, if any.
    if i := len(line) - 1; i >= 0 {
        b.lastByte = int(line[i])
        b.lastRuneSize = -1
    }

    return
}

(go/src/bufio/bufio.go, line 347, Go 1.22)
As far as I understand, this can cause the loop in collectFragments to run forever. However, since ErrBufferFull is explicitly ignored, I feel this is by design, and I'm missing something.
Can someone help me understand? Thanks!

This is explained in ReadSlice docs:

ReadSlice fails with error ErrBufferFull if the buffer fills without a delim.

You should also notice that if ErrBufferFull is returned, the algorithm continues reading after appending the slice to another, so it reads in chunks.

I understand that in ReadSlice if the buffer is full, the whole b.buf is returned. However a copy of the buffer, buf, is appended to totalBuffers in collectFragments, so I don't think that somehow fixes the full b.buf.

Note that buf is allocated only once. Data read from the input stream is stored in buf. BufferFull error simply means delimiter is not found in the buf, so another load is necessary.
